# What adjective (other than "last") means "most-recent previous"?

Tags: adjectives

If I were to say "the previous item" or "the prior item" or "the preceding item", I *could* be referring either to the *most-recent* previous item, or to any other item logically coming before the current one.

How can I refer to not just any prior item, but the *last* or *most-recent* item, without using the word "last"?

I'm especially interested in a word that would be a suitable replacement for the "most-recent previous" in technical writing.

---

By way of clarification...

I'm looking for alternative terminology that de-emphasizes the concept of time and emphasizes the concept of logical ordering.  The word "recent" seems too attached to the concept of time.  The phrase "most-recent previous" is, frankly, a mouthful --- especially if used repeatedly. The word "last" has the potential to be confused with the ultimate in an entire series, rather than merely the immediate predecessor of any specifically-referred to item the series.

Comment: I'm not seeing in your question the problem you're having with with using "most recent".

Comment: What @Kristina said. We *do* actually have *penultimate* and *antepenultimate* (even [*preantepenultimate*](http://unusedwords.com/2012/11/30/preantepenultimate/) if anyone needs it, though I've never come across *ultimate* used to mean *the one after the penultimate*. Anyway, absent any explanation of why OP can't/won't use ***most recent***, I've closevoted because I think it's unclear what exactly he's after and why.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Because in some technical writing, the concept of time implied by the term "recent" is a little strange.

Also, "most-recent previous" is 3 words; it would be nice it there was a good 1 word to use in place of the 3 words.

Comment: I agree that one word would be nice.  As @FumbleFingers said, I've not heard of *ultimate* being used as the occurrence after penultimate either.  Maybe it's a regional thing but your "most-recent previous" sounds strange to me.  Where I'm from, we just say "most recent" (without the hyphen).

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  Frankly, the original example I gave was poor.  My question really pertains mostly to technical, often mathematical, writing.  Colloquially, "most recent" is certainly sufficient and clear.  So, I have now editing my original question; hopefully it's not quite as misleading now :)

Comment: Can't you identify the "current" item of interest as S-sub-n and then refer to the prior one as S-sub-n-minus-1?

Comment: @Jim Mathematically, yes. What I'm looking for are alternatives by which to say *in words* what can be easily said in mathematical nomenclature.

Comment: @ synaptik: If I understand you correctly, you're saying you don't like "recent" because it implies a *chronological sequence*, and you don't like "last" because it implies *there are/will be no more elements in the list*. But it seems to me even with a non-chronological sequence like π (pi), it's perfectly reasonable to refer to the ***last/latest** [known]* digit. I think it's now proven that there will never be a "final" digit of π, but it is "chronological" in the sense that [**over time**, more digits continue to be "discovered."](http://www.numberworld.org/misc_runs/pi-5t/details.html)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You've got me right on "recent".  For "last", it's not that there are truly no more elements in the list, it's just that using the word "last" suggests the very last element in some list or sublist.  In other words, if there is a list `X_1, X_2,...,X_i,...,X_n,...`, and I'm currently talking about `X_i`, then using the word "last" to refer to element `X_{i-1}` may tend to cause the reader to think about element `X_n`.  In other words, using the word "last" causes the reader to look to the end, whereas I merely want the reader to look to the immediate left of the current element.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ...having said that, I think you're probably right that "last" is suitable much of the time.  If my writing is effective, then context should add enough meaning to the word "last" to prevent confusion.

Comment: @ synaptik: I closevoted as "unclear" when you first posted the question. I'm not sure I'd do that with the current revised wording, but I still don't think your intended context is clear enough. For example, much may depend on how obvious it is that there are (or *may* be) more elements *after* the one you're focussing on, and how relevant *time* is to the possibility of those later (in the series) elements becoming "current" later (in time). Only exact context tells us whether *most recent, last, latest, preceding*, or something else might be the best word to use.

Comment: In technical parlance, the abbreviations MRU & LRU have been in use for long, most likely because there is no suitable single-word substitute for the phrases *Most Recently Used (Accessed)* & *Least Recently Used (Accessed)*.

Comment: WIth tongue planted firmly in cheek, I propose 1B4 an acronym for the "one before."

Answer (score 2):

If you say

> "the previous item" or "the prior item" or "the preceding item"

The definite article indicates exactly what you mean to say.

The indefinite article would be less specific

> "a previous item" or "a prior item" or "a preceding item"

Answer (score 1):

What about "My latest experience was . . ."

Comment: But "latest" means current.  I mean the one immediately preceding current.

Comment: Ah. I'll bet you don't like "penultimate" though. :-)

Comment: That would be good... but that means next to last in a series.  So if I'm referring to an item, X, somewhere in the middle of a series of items, and I wish to also refer to the item that immediately precedes item X, then it would *not* be the penultimate item.  Or, at the very least, the use of "penultimate" would be potentially confusing.

Comment: Then "Ultimate to X" would be the immediately preceding item to X, and "penultimate to X" would the item before that.

Comment: Really?  Hmm, then that might be just the ticket! :)  I didn't think about using (pen-)ultimate in that way.  Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not grasp this notion that every imaginable concept must be expressible in English as a single word. Writing and speaking usually involve combining words into phrases, clauses, sentences, and paragraphs.

"Preceding" means before "now" and may refer to one item or more than one. If you are discussing British kings who ruled before George III, you can quite properly say "the preceding kings." If, however, you say "the preceding king," you mean George II. If there is potential ambiguity in "preceding" because the number of preceding items exceeds one and you are using "preceding" as a noun rather than an adjective, then any potential ambiguity can be eliminated by saying either "all the preceding" or else "the immediately preceding."

I agree that "preceding" may refer to chronology or a previously specified list. I do not think there is a lexical way to distinguish between the two meanings.  If you have a list and want to refer to the last in historical time, I'd list them in chronological order to avoid any ambiguity. If you list in an order that reflects increasing importance but not chronology, you can avoid ambiguity by saying "the last in the preceding list."

Answer (score 0):

I think you can say "one version prior to the current one" or "the version preceding the current one".

Comment: It would help if you seemed a little more convinced of your own answer. Additional explanation as to why these are better options would also improve this answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think you're looking for "preceding". Preceding will always mean the most previous to X, regardless of wherever X falls chronologically. X-1 is precedent to X.